# Batch file output redirection to a text file; not complete

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, redirection

Examples:
Parent-Dir= 'USA zip-code', Sub-dir(s)= 'yyyymmdd'
Example filename= 139_7_IPC1_NVR16-8580_20230101104640.jpg

There are six-hundred and ninety-nine files in the directory-tree that the, regex within the `For /F` loop (below), can see --only when I replace:
`@echo !_i:~-18,-4!> "%cd%\_A\_A.txt"`with `copy "%%i" "%cd%\_A"`or `@echo !_i:~-18,-4!`, without redirection; will this function properly. Using the 'echo redirection' only redirects one line that complies with

`set "_i=%%i"`
`@echo !_i:~-18,-4!> "%cd%\_A\_A.txt"`; which would output 20240203075520. There should be six-hundred and ninety-nine entries matching the file output when using `copy "%%i" "%cd%\_A"`.

```
    @echo off
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /S /b %1*.jpg ^| findstr /r ^_2024[0-3][0-9]..0[0-7]') do (

     set "_i=%%i"
     @echo !_i:~-18,-4!> "%cd%\_A\_A.txt" 
               )
```

What have I broken?

Comment: `> "%cd%\_A\_A.txt` should be `>> "%cd%\_A\_A.txt` so that it appends each time through the loop (it's currently overwriting). See [Command Redirection, Pipes - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Comment: @DavidPostill <sigh>, thank you. I keep making these silly mistakes. I truly apologize for wasting this forums time, but after more than four hours at this issue, I could not see my mistake [hiding in plain sight] given its a loop and was overwriting the previous entry.

Comment: one thing, what it uses as an argument, what is passing as *`%1`*?

Comment: zOk, but could you plz just answer the question asked?

Comment: @Io-o manually typed alpha-numeric text from the cli is passed, without any special chars.